# Does non-response bias affect the validity of a statistical model?

Tags: regression, survey, glmm, weights

I want to build a (generalised linear mixed) model on some survey data. The PROC GENMOD command in SAS doesn't admit weighting in the sense of survey weights. I am not interested in population-level frequencies, but do want to draw valid conclusions about how covariates interact with each other and the dependent variable in the real world. Does the lack of weights matter?

Comment: What is a "valid" conclusion about the "real world" if not an inference about the population?

Comment: An opportunity to sound clever?

Comment: I don't follow.  I'm not trying to be snarky. I just think you're in fact doing what you say you aren't doing.

Comment: I agree that conclusions about the real world are inferences about the population. What I'm saying above is that I am not interested in population-level frequencies, but in how different characteristics are related to each other. I am using the ending "in the real world" to emphasise that I am asking whether the conclusions from unweighted data will be applicable outside the sample. I'm now pretty sure they won't, though. I'm not necessarily keen on exploring the semantic further, but I'm grateful that you have engaged with my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in making inferences on a group larger than your sample, I suspect that the answer is "yes," but how much bias is introduced?

The typical argument is that those who do not answer the survey are categorically different than those who do. Chapter 6 of the textbook Survey Methodology by Groves et al and related papers, partition non-response into three groups:

1. refusal
2. non-contact or miss (never available)
3. inability to respond (eg, language barrier)

If a cause behind one or more of these non-response categories is correlated with your outcome of interest, then there is a danger that your estimates  will be biased.

In some instances, you may be able to control for the non-response causes through modeling or weighting. When this is not a possibility, AAPOR recommends that, as a minimum, you **report the response rate** (various formulas might be found on their website).

The textbook chapter mentioned above as well as other research papers on this topic have found that well thought out and executed surveys can produce unbiased results even with a fairly high response rate, but these are typically surveys conducted with the great care.

My recommendation is to report the response rate (or a couple response rates based on different formulas) and discuss how this might affect your estimates based on the literature.

Comment: This is a good response, but seems more relevant to the generalization of means, proportions, etc. to the larger population. With respect to non-response bias in a model, there will only be bias if non-response is correlated with *both* the outcome and predictor. Am I wrong? In practice, survey weights are rarely included in regression models, though I know there is some debate about this. But say women are under-represented and so we post-stratify for calculation of means, etc., that makes sense, but if we include gender as a covariate in our model with no weights, then where is the bias?

Comment: I appreciate your thoughts. I can easily think of scenarios where unweighted analysis would create problems in drawing general conclusions. Let's say blue-collar workers were prevalent in a particular part of the country, and also took more time to get re-employed. If I had fewer blue-collar workers than is typical, since they may feel they have better things to do than answer a survey, then my analysis of propensity of re-employment of blue-collar workers would not be problematic per se. However, the part of the country they are from would over-predict reemployment.